# Typescript, function argument inside arrow function

Tags: function, typescript, parameters, arrow-functions

In this code, I add an action for a "bet", and pass its id as a parameter to a function. But when I call this arrow function later, the argument of `this.undoBet` equals to `this.local_bets[this.local_bets.length].bet_id` - the last `bet_id` that was passed inside the loop.

How to make it so that inside every arrow function, `this.undoBet` would preserve the `bet_id` assigned to it in that loop?

```
for (var k in this.local_bets) {

    var bet = this.local_bets[k];

    if (bet.status == BetStatus.accepted) {

        // Here bet_id is correct for every "bet" variable

        this.addUndo( "undo_bet", () => {

            // When calling this later, bet_id equals to one that belongs to the last bet inside this.local_bets

            this.undoBet( bet.bet_id );
        });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common JavaScript mistake. Its because `for (var k in this.local_bets) {` the index will actually be the *last* one by the time the continuing function executes.

## Fix

use `let`:

```
for (let k in this.local_bets) {

    let bet = this.local_bets[k];
```

## More

This is covered here https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/let.html

Answer (score 2):

Try this (another local variable will be scoped in the each new undo bet function):

```
this.local_bets
    .filter(bet => bet.status == BetStatus.accepted)
    .forEach(bet => this.addUndo("undo_bet", () => this.undoBet(bet.bet_id)));
```

Comment: Although I find function chining more elegant, I used a dictionary here, so it wouldn't work. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

All solutions are good, but better is to use **`const`** keyword when variable is not supposed to change. Check the code below:

```
for (const k in this.local_bets) {

const bet = this.local_bets[k];

if (bet.status == BetStatus.accepted) {

    // Here bet_id is correct for every "bet" variable

    this.addUndo( "undo_bet", () => {

        // When calling this later, bet_id equals to one that belongs to the last bet inside this.local_bets

        this.undoBet( bet.bet_id );
    });

}
```

}